# ReadfromKafka transform Python Sdk

Tags: python, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam-io

I'm reading data messages from Kafka server running on Compute Engine vm (GCP). Using kafka-python module (which runs a kafka client within Python) I am able to read messages from topic.
Instead, with external Ptransform lastly implemented in Python Sdk of Apache Beam (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3788), the process is stuck at ReadfromKafka transform without outputting any record present on topic.
Here is my code:

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=p_opts) as pipeline:

    # Read from Kafka into a PCollection.
    messages = (pipeline | "ReadfromKafka" >> kafka.ReadFromKafka({'bootstrap.servers': '<Ip_address>:9092', 'auto_offset_reset': 'earliest',
                'enable_auto_commit': 'False'}, ['<topic_name>'])) | "Log_results" >> beam.ParDo(LogResults())
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. Let me try to get back to you in a bit...

Comment: Are you using Dataflow ? If so, you need Dataflow runner V2 for using transforms in Kafka.py. Please see instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-runner-v2

Comment: Are you using Dataflow?

Comment: any more details MAtteo?

Comment: Tried extracting and logging Kafka message value with 
 `class KafkaRowParser(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, message):
        data = message.value
        yield data
`

but on StackDriver I'm getting just details about ConsumerConfig values. Nothing about message payload.

Comment: can you please file a support ticket? let me know if you don't have access to support, and we'll figure something out.